# Data Not Showing in Preview, but Does Show in Field Data

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which I created a data source link to from an ADO.NET connection. Within the dataset is a table called vendorPP.  When I drag this field onto my report, and hit preview, no data shows. If I right click on the field and say browse field data, I can see the vendors email address that I would like to appear on the report. I am placing the field in a page header.  I have checked the font color, and verified that field is not suppressed in any way. I can drag other Fields on there and they appear just fine.  Anyone had a similar problem or know how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: When you browse the data, is the first record a blank record?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your report structure. If you put the email field in the page header, it will only the show the first record in the table, which might be a blank record. Try grouping your report by the vendor name and then putting the email field in the group header. Now you should see the vendor name and corresponding email in the group header.

Hope that helps,

Chris